# Cross-platform notification service

Tags: java, android, ios, notifications

I would like to develop an application using push notification service (like Whatsapp). What kind of service would I have to use to manage all kinds of operating system?

Comment: https://parse.com/questions/cross-platform-push-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a backend like Parse.

http://www.parse.com

It's a good starting place and supports all different types of OS's.
It stores data, provides analytical stats and also allows you to send push notifications to 1 million unique devices - without paying a penny.

Hope this helps.

Cheers
Ryann